# How to obtain a fluid multi columns layout in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two posts in a row but if the height of the posts is different there's a space between the two vertical post, How can I remove this space? (I want obtaining a layout like google plus multi columns)

**The code is like this now:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-6"> other things here </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> other things here </div>
  </div>
<div class="row-fluid">
... ...
```

Comment: Thats what you want? http://masonry.desandro.com/ .. If yes, I think is not possible only with css... you have to use a little bit of jQuery as well

Comment: Yes, it's what I want, thank you!

Comment: No problem, I will answer below for others users and you can accept the answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create it only with CSS, as specified in comments you can use this plugin:

http://masonry.desandro.com/