# layout the different cols with different height in the same row issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use bootstrap3 to layout like this:

http://ppt.cc/4KCS

But the grid system seems that the different columns in the same row can't has different height, or it may appear white block.

My code below, but if I change the height value of right side column, a whole row will crash!

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-6 column" style="background:red; height:40%;">test
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 column" style="background:blue;">test
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-6 column" style="background:yellow; height:50%;">test
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 column" style="background:green;">tset
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column" style="background:gray; height:10%;">test
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain a fluid multi columns layout in bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991119/how-to-obtain-a-fluid-multi-columns-layout-in-bootstrap)

Comment: Bootstrap columns module is probably not the answer to your problem. You should look at the [Flexbox module](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you were thinking but maybe it's good starting point:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 column">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 column" style="background:red; height:40px;">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 column" style="background:green; height:20px;">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 column" >
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 column" style="background:blue; height:20px;">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 column" style="background:yellow; height:30px;">

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 column" style="background:grey; height:30px;">

        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qG787/

Comment: Weird. When I'm opening it in my browser it works. But if I use Incognito mode it doesn't.

Comment: @Paulie_D it works :) just resize preview window. It's because of "col-md-" class and media queries in bootstrap. I've update the code to cover all cases.

Comment: hi @Zentoaku, I think your code is really help for me!! Because I use this solution in my local and it looks well!

But I don't know why the layout is broken when I change "px" to "%" in jsfiddle.

Comment: @陳柏伸 glad to hear that :) please mark answer if it's good for you :)